# Spring Tool Suite finds spring-boot integration test configuration and does not start main application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-tool-suite

I have a little struggle with Spring Tool Suite in combination with spring-boot.

I created a custom Maven spring-boot-web-application including several JUnit tests, one of this test is an integration test which has a configuration for the testapplication.

If I want to start the spring-boot-web-application via Spring Tool Suite ( run as -> Spring Boot Application ) the application does not start because both configurations ( src/main/java, src/test/java ) are found and conflict each other.

As soon I remove the test resources from the buildpath the application starts as expected.

Is there any setting in Spring Tool Suite to prevent the test resources are added to the classpath when starting the spring-boot-web-application?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I am using Spring Tool Suite 3.6.4.RELEASE and spring-boot 1.2.3.RELEASE and Java 1.8

Comment: I recalll recently fixing a bug that may be the same as this one. Hover your description of the problem is a bit too vague to be sure. https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-4085

Comment: Please clarify what 'fails to start' actually does. Is there an error? Please inlcude the error message / stacktrace.

Comment: @Kris Thanks for your reply! To have a better discussion base I created a little demo application https://github.com/flexguse/spring-boot-integration-test. Maybe this is not a problem of Spring Tool Suite but of my application configuration - Christoph

Comment: Can you add more details on how you 'start the app'. I mean, there are many ways (menus, toolbar buttons etc) in STS / Eclipse to run things. you just say "When I start X" which is rather vague. Be as precise as possible and I can try to reproduce it.

Comment: Package Explorer -> src/main/java -> de.flexguse.demo -> SpringBootIntegrationDemoApplication.java -> right mouse click -> Run as -> Spring Boot App ( Alt + Shift + X, B). Or open SpringBootIntegrationDemoApplication.java in the Java Editor and use Alt + Shift + X, B or use the little round green run icon. All three 'start the app' methods lead to the same result, the test configuration is found.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it and seem to get a different error as you. My guess is that indeed the problem you are hitting with the test resources being on the classpath is the bug I fixed, but your project has other issues causing it to fail running. These other issues do not look like bugs in the tooling since I get the exact same error (see https://gist.github.com/kdvolder/fdc1883336553d2e7f03) running inside STS as I do packaging and running the jar on the commandline (after fixing a minor problem with the main classname in your pom having '-' in the package name).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

STS 3.6.4 has a [bug](https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-4085) in it that causes the classpath for "Run As >> Spring Boot App" on maven projects to include 'test stuff' (source folders and jar dependencies) to be on the runtime classpath.

The bug is a regression as it did not exist in 3.6.3. The bug is fixed already in master and the fix will be part of STS 3.7.0. You can get this fix today by updating your STS installation from the nightly update site:

http://dist.springframework.org/snapshot/IDE/nightly/

Open "Help >> Install New Software" and paste the above link in the "work with" field and then install the "Core" pieces. The installer will inform you that you already have these and will perform an upgrade instead.

After this upgrade is succesful, "Run As >> Boot App" should no longer have test stuff on the runtime classpath.

Comment: I beleave this is the correct answer w.r.t. your question. I.e "How do I avoid test resource on my classpath". However, note that your demo project seems to have other problems besides this, I think those are probably unrelated problems and... if you can't work those out, you should ask a new question.

Comment: Hi Kris, thanks a lot! I'll try the nightly snapshot and if I still have trouble I know for sure the reason is in my code ;)

Comment: The demo application was updated so it can be used as an example spring-boot application having an integration test using spring-security